# htaccess rewrite rule 'page numbers' problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've added a .htaccess file to my root folder for the purposes of rewriting dynamic URLs into static ones. This seems to have been done successfully but I am having problems with page numbers.

For example, if you were to visit a static page `/widgets`, the first page of the products is fine....but subsequent pages show up as `/products.php?cat=27&pg=2` etc. What I want is for subsequent pages to be in the form of `/widgets-pg2` or `/widgets?pg=2`.

Below is my rewrite rule that I used for the initial category page:-

```
RewriteRule ^widgets$ products.php?cat=27
```

If any of you experts can help with this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow a query string after your rewritten URL use the `[QSA]` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^widgets$ products.php?cat=27 [QSA]
```

A link would than be:

```
http://example.org/widgets?pg=167&perpage=100&tralala=Hi!
```

Comment: The QSA creates the relevant pages, but these still need to be added as links.  For this, the answer can be found here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422244/adjusting-a-php-function-so-that-it-displays-link-in-the-form-of-widgetspg2

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting the cat to change as well? You'd need to account for that in your URL as well:

e.g. www.site.com/widgets/27/2 could be rewritten as:

```
RewriteRule ^widgets/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ products.php?cat=$1&pg=$2
```

If widgets will always be cat 27 then you can change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^widgets$ products.php?cat=27 [QSA]
```

which is query string append

Comment: /widgets would always be cat27 whilst /doodles is cat21.  So for widgets I did as you mentioned above (adding the QSA) and the pages in the form of /widgets?pg=2 or /widgets?pg=3 work when I enter them in the browser manually.  But the current links did not automatically change and they still point to:- products.php?cat=27&pg=2 or products.php?cat=27&pg=3.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^widgets-pg(.+)$ products.php?cat=27&pg=$1
```

After that, [go here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) :)

Comment: Tried this and it seemed to work for the /widgets but didn't work for /doodles or /other-stuff which resulted in a 'Not Found' error.  Then a strange thing happened: when I changed the rewrite rule for 'widgets' back to the original one, saving and uploading it to the server seems to made no difference.  It still works.

Comment: Ignore the above message.  The reason is that I had a separate widgets.php file which was being referred and caused a clash.

Comment: If you want it to work for `/doodles` or anything else, you need to also add those rules in, one line per category.

Comment: Originally thought it was working for /Widgets but then later realised it doesn't.  I get a '404 Not Found' error.  

The following works:- 'RewriteRule ^widgets$ products.php?cat=27 [QSA]', 
But requires me to enter the following address manually in the browser:- 'mywebsite.com/widgets?pg=2'

The link to page 2 still leads to:- 'products.php?cat=27&pg=2'.  So I now need to know how to change this link as its dynamically generated.  

The following is the php code for this page:- 

http://freetexthost.com/3ubiydspzm

The page number links are at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following but it resulted in a '404 Not Found' error when I go to /widgets:-

```
RewriteRule ^widgets-pg(.+)$ products.php?cat=27&pg=$1
```

And I tried the following:-

```
RewriteRule ^widgets$ products.php?cat=27 [QSA]
```

This worked correctly but to go to page two of the widgets page, I need to type in the browser:-

```
/widgets?pg=2
```

But the actual 'page 2' link still leads to:-

```
products.php?cat=27&pg=2
```

So apart from a rewrite rule....maybe I need a separate redirection rule?  Or maybe need to change the page number links.  But since these are dynamically generated, I'm not sure how to do this.

The following is the PHP code for the page:- http://freetexthost.com/3ubiydspzm